# Vacuum expectation value of the Wilson loop in pure QED

Tags: gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, wilson-loop

In Chapter 57 of Srednicki's QFT book he derives the generating function of pure QED and finds
\begin{align*}
Z(J) = \exp\left[\frac{i}{2}\int\mathrm{d}^4x\,\mathrm{d}^4y\ J_\mu(x) \Delta^{\mu\nu}(x-y)J_\nu(y)\right]
\end{align*}
with the propagator in the Feynman gauge
\begin{align*}
\Delta^{\mu\nu}(x-y) = \eta^{\mu\nu} \int\frac{\mathrm{d}^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{e^{ik(x-y)}}{k^2-i\varepsilon}
\end{align*}
Then in chapter 82 he goes on to calculate the VEV of the Wilson loop
\begin{align*}
\langle 0| W(\gamma)|0\rangle = \int\mathcal{D}A\ \exp\left[ie\oint_{\gamma}\mathrm{d}x^\mu\, A_\mu(x)\right] \exp\left[-\int\mathrm{d}^4x\, F^2\right]
\end{align*}
He argues that by identifying the source $J$ as $J^\mu = ie\oint_{\gamma}\mathrm{d}x^\mu$ we can simply insert this in the expression for the generating functional above and finds (now everything in euclidean signature)
\begin{align*}
\langle 0 | W(\gamma) |0\rangle = \exp\left[-\frac{e^2}{2}\oint_\gamma\mathrm{d}x^\mu\oint_\gamma \mathrm{d}y^\nu \Delta_{\mu\nu}(x-y)\right]
\end{align*}
I don't understand what happened to the two integrals over all of spacetime in the generating functional. It's unclear to me what would be meant by an integral of the form
\begin{align*}
\int\mathrm{d}^4x\ \oint_\gamma \mathrm{d}x^\mu\ f_\mu(x) 
\end{align*}
Is this meant as some fixed loop 'shape' and integrating over all possible starting points, but wouldn't this lead to some type of volume divergence? Or does the integral somehow drop out cause we really only consider the actual path $\gamma$ and there's somehow some type of delta function implied?

(Alternatively this is problem 15.3 in Peskin and Schroeder)

Comment: To be more precise, using minkowski signature, the substitution he uses is $J^\mu(x)=e\oint dy^\mu \delta(x-y)$ so that: $$i\int d^4x J(x)\cdot A(x)= ie\oint  d^\mu x A_\mu(x)$$ This means that it is simply the vev of a particular source given by the formula.

Comment: Ah yes I think that makes sense. If you write I short answer I'll accept it.